# Não consigo colocar varios elementos encontrados com Xpath do Selenium em Python

Tags: python, for, selenium-webdriver, csv, xpath

"""
Meu codigo é para entrar em um site de noticia e extrair com Xpath todos os titulos, subtitulos e links das materias, depois colocar em listas e esportar em CSV.

Mas no CSV exportado fica repetindo apenas um titulo, um subtitulo e um link.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd



servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)

url_do_site = "https://br.noticias.yahoo.com/"
navegador.get(url_do_site)


# Finding Elements
containers = navegador.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//li [@class ="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]')
print(containers)

titles = []
subtitles = []
links = []
for container in containers:
    title = container.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li [@class ="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]/div/div/div/h3/a/u').text
    subtitle = container.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li [@class ="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]/div/div/div/p').text
    link = container.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div [@class ="Cf"]/div /h3/a').get_attribute('href')
    titles.append(title)
    subtitles.append(subtitle)
    links.append(link)

# Exporting data to a CSV file
my_dict = {'title': titles, 'subtitle': subtitles, 'link': links}
df_headlines = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df_headlines.to_csv('headline.csv')

navegador.quit()
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente desta forma:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv

# Obter o HTML da página do site
page = requests.get(url_do_site)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# Extrair os títulos das matérias usando o XPATH
titles = tree.xpath('//li[@class="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]/div/div/div/h3/a/u/text()')

# Extrair os subtítulos das matérias usando o XPATH
subtitles = tree.xpath('//li[@class="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]/div/div/div/p/text()')

# Extrair os links das matérias usando o XPATH
links = tree.xpath('//li[@class="js-stream-content Pos(r)"]/div/h3/a/@href')

# Criar uma lista de dicionários com os títulos, subtítulos e links
articles = []
for title, subtitle, link in zip(titles, subtitles, links):
    articles.append({'title': title, 'subtitle': subtitle, 'link': link})

# Escrever os dados em um arquivo CSV
with open('articles.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'subtitle', 'link']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for article in articles:
        writer.writerow(article)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: não funciou, de esse erro: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"div/div/div/h3/a/u"}

Comment: O erro "NoSuchElementException" ocorre quando o Selenium não consegue encontrar um elemento na página HTML usando o caminho de busca do XPath especificado. Isso pode acontecer por vários motivos, como:

O caminho de busca do XPath está incorreto ou inválido.
O elemento que você está tentando encontrar não existe na página HTML.
O elemento que você está tentando encontrar ainda não foi carregado na página quando o código foi executado.

Comment: Para corrigir esse erro, você pode tentar:

Verificar se o caminho de busca do XPath está correto e se ele corresponde ao elemento que você está tentando encontrar na página HTML. Você pode usar a ferramenta de inspeção de elementos do seu navegador para verificar o código HTML da página e verificar se o caminho de busca do XPath está correto.
Adicionar um delay antes de tentar encontrar o elemento, para dar tempo para que o elemento seja carregado na página. Você pode usar a função time.sleep() do Python para adicionar um delay de alguns segundos antes de tentar encontrar o elemento.

Comment: Tratar a exceção "NoSuchElementException" com um bloco try-except para evitar que o código pare de funcionar quando o elemento não for encontrado. Isso permite que o código continue executando mesmo que o elemento não seja encontrado, o que é útil se você estiver tentando encontrar elementos em uma página que pode ter elementos dinâmicos ou que só são carregados em determinadas condições. Isso foi o que encontrei.

Comment: colocando duas barras antes dos XPATHs que vc passou, corrigiu o erro mas voltou a extrair  apenas um titulo, um subtitulo e um link.